# Array of Structures:No matching function to call to and taking user input

Tags: c++

I have written a code for Knapsack problem.The code is working perfectly when i hardcode the inputs but now i want to take the inputs from the user in the array of structures but it is showing error.How can i achieve this?
original code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct Item{
    int value;
    int weight;
    Item(int value,int weight):value(value),weight(weight){

    }
};

bool cmp(struct Item a,struct Item b){
    float r1=(float)a.value/a.weight;
    float r2=(float)b.value/b.weight;
    //cout<<r1<<" "<<r2<<endl;
    return r1>r2;
}

void knapsack(int m,int n,struct Item arr[]){
    sort(arr,arr+n,cmp);
   /* for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ //new sorted array
        cout<<arr[i].value<<" "<<arr[i].weight<<" ";
    }*/
    cout<<endl;
    float result[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        result[i]=0.0;
    }
    int rem=m;
    int j=0;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(arr[j].weight>rem){
            break;
        }
        else{
            result[j]=1;
            rem=rem-arr[j].weight;
        }
    }
    if(j<n){
        result[j]=(float)rem/arr[j].weight;
    }
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
        cout<<result[k]<<" ";
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Item arr[]={{25,18},{24,15},{15,10}};
    knapsack(20,3,arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Now i want to take user input in the array of structures but it shows an error "no matching function to call to"

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct Item{
    int value;
    int weight;
    Item(int value,int weight):value(value),weight(weight){

    }
};

bool cmp(struct Item a,struct Item b){
    float r1=(float)a.value/a.weight;
    float r2=(float)b.value/b.weight;
    //cout<<r1<<" "<<r2<<endl;
    return r1>r2;
}

void knapsack(int m,int n,struct Item arr[]){
    sort(arr,arr+n,cmp);
   /* for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ //new sorted array
        cout<<arr[i].value<<" "<<arr[i].weight<<" ";
    }*/
    cout<<endl;
    float result[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        result[i]=0.0;
    }
    int rem=m;
    int j=0;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        if(arr[j].weight>rem){
            break;
        }
        else{
            result[j]=1;
            rem=rem-arr[j].weight;
        }
    }
    if(j<n){
        result[j]=(float)rem/arr[j].weight;
    }
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++){
        cout<<result[k]<<" ";
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Item arr[10];
    int n,m;
    cin>>m>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i].value>>arr[i].weight;
    }
    knapsack(m,n,arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the entire error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code:

```
struct Item{
    int value;
    int weight;
    Item(int value,int weight):value(value),weight(weight){

    }
};
```

There is no default constructor. So the below line fails:

```
struct Item arr[10];
```

But the following line works:

```
struct Item arr[]={{25,18},{24,15},{15,10}};
```

**Solution**<sup>[1]</sup>: Provide a default constructor or remove the explicit constructor.

---

<sup>[1] There may be more problems in the code, but I looked into the one you pointed in your question.</sup>

Comment: that worked but why do i need to provide a default constructor?

Comment: @MickeyMouse When you did `struct Item arr[10];`, an array for 10 Item elements was created. For each element, default constructor has to be called so as to initialize the individual elements of the array with proper values. That's why compiler expects it to have a default constructor, which it failed to find.

Comment: @MickeyMouse When you provide a constructor by yourself to `struct Item`, you don't get implicit [Default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) for your class so you have to provide one explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You have provided parameterized constructor `Item(int value,int weight)`, **so compiler won't generate default constructor** by itself.

You have to define the default constructor explicitly to make the below statement work since it needs default constructor.

```
struct Item arr[10];
```

But the below line of code uses the parameterized constructor you have provided.

```
struct Item arr[]={{25,18},{24,15},{15,10}};
```

Comment: I don't see anything different in this answer from the already posted answer.

Comment: @KunalPuri The value is that the compiler doesn't generate the default constructor since there is already a user defined constructor.

Comment: It should have been comment to an already posted answer, not a new answer.

Comment: @KunalPuri I am answering using Android phone and it took a while to write it and then I noticed your answer. But since this answer was more informative, I left it as it is so that the OP can choose which one seems to be more helpful.

Comment: That was also a good answer, though. It included one important point.

Comment: @KunalPuri Correct me if I am wrong. SO doesn't have any hard rule that there should be only one answer. As long as the answer is more helpful than other answers, people will get benefited. I am not saying the other answer is not good. What I am saying is this answer gives more clarity to anyone who doesn't know the root cause of the issue.

Comment: There is no hard rule. But it makes more sense to improve an existing answer instead of posting a new one. I think People will be feel more helped by seeing one wonderful answer, rather than seeing two answers with one having slightly more information than the accepted one.

Comment: @KunalPuri You should try answering from smartphone. Then you will understand :-)